# INSERT INTO VALUES when select returns more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

This is my query :

```sql
INSERT INTO [allocation_schematic.types].plans_into_type(id_plan, id_type) 
VALUES (@idplan, ( SELECT tiv.id_type 
FROM [allocation_schematic.types].type_into_voltage tiv 
WHERE id_voltage = @idvoltage ));
```

The SELECT subquery returns more than 1 value and I know it because I want to insert a new row for each value the subquery returns.

I get:

> SQL Error 512 : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not
>   permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the
>   subquery is used as an expression.

I couldn't find a solution on forums so may someone give me a hint about how I can do it there.

Thanks for anybody helping !

Answer (score 4):

The following query should work:

```
INSERT INTO [allocation_schematic.types].plans_into_type(id_plan, id_type) 
SELECT @idplan, tiv.id_type 
FROM [allocation_schematic.types].type_into_voltage tiv 
WHERE id_voltage = @idvoltage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of VALUES use SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO [allocation_schematic.types].plans_into_type(id_plan, id_type) 
SELECT @idplan,  tiv.id_type 
FROM [allocation_schematic.types].type_into_voltage tiv 
WHERE id_voltage = @idvoltage;
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried something similar but with a wrong syntax before posting ahah

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add your property as part of your subquery, like this

```sql
INSERT INTO [allocation_schematic.types].plans_into_type(id_plan, id_type) 
SELECT @idplan, tiv.id_type 
FROM [allocation_schematic.types].type_into_voltage tiv 
WHERE id_voltage = @idvoltage;
```